# Permissions issues on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, permissions

This question has been asked several times but none of the solutions fix it in my situation.

I am running Apache on Mac OSX Lion. This `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php` URL triggers 2 major problems:

```
Change the permissions of the "app/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
Change the permissions of the "app/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
```

Following the [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) under "Setting up Permissions":

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
sudo chmod +a "_www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

That doesn't solve the problems, so then I tried:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
```

That doesn't work either. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: my colleague at work on MacOS used the `sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache` solution and it worked for him. What exactly is happening after you chmod?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Some preliminary explanations:

- In order to enhance the performance of your website, Symfony2 needs to cache a lot of data and it does this by writing *compiled files* into your `app/cache` directory.
- In order to propose powerful debugging and monitoring facilities, Symfony2 needs to track your website behavior and it does this by writing *trace files* into your `app/logs` directory.

Some words about Apache:

- Apache runs under a specific `user` and a specific `group` (usually `www-data` for both, but you have to check your installation to find the used ones. For example, if you search in the `/etc/apache2/envvars` in Linux, you will have two variables `APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data`).
- It means that when you build your website upon Symfony2 shoulders and you run it under Apache, **every writes and reads are made on behalf of the Apache `user` and `group`**.

Analyze of your problems:

- First of all you have errors like:

  ```
  Change the permissions of the "app/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
  Change the permissions of the "app/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
  ```

  because your `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders are not writable for your Apache `user` and `group`.
- Secondly, by executing:

  ```
  sudo chmod +a "_www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
  sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
  ```

  you are modifying the *Access Control List (ACL)* of the `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders in order to grant some permissions to `whoami` (basically you) and to `_www`.
  This approach does not work and can have two origins:

  1. You are modifying ACLs, but are your kernel and your file system configured to take into account ACLs?
  2. You are giving some permissions to `whoami` and to `_www`, but have you checked that your Apache instance runs under one of these users?
- Thirdly your colleagues solve the problem by executing:

  ```
  sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache
  ```

  This approach works because of two reasons:

  1. You give all permissions (reads and writes) to every user on your system (`777`), so you are sure that at least your Apache user and group have also the needed permissions to write in `app/cache`.
  2. You do it recursively (`-R`), so all the nested folders created in the `app/cache` directory are also concerned by the new permissions.

Simple solution:

1. Delete the content of your `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders:

   ```
   rm -rf app/cache/*
   rm -rf app/logs/*
   ```
2. Give all permissions (reads and writes) to your `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders:

   ```
   chmod 777 app/cache
   chmod 777 app/logs
   ```

Remarks:

- There are also other solutions (with a greater difficulty) like giving permission to the specific Apache user and group and using ACLs for fine tuning.

Comment: That was a great answer, but now after deleting and giving new permissions to the folders the welcome page _http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_ shows an empty/blank page. According to the config.php page everything was ok...

Comment: You're welcome ;) The fact that you get a blank page is not related to permission issues. Have you checked that you have a not empty template for your index page? Maybe you can post a new question if you think that this is a really issue.

Comment: But doesnt the template come with a  fresh installation of Symfony?
Are you sure that the template is not loaded because of a permissions issue?

Comment: Yes, if you have a fresh Symfony2, you have a default template for the index page. It's wired! But when I see your URL localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php I see a problem with you web server configuration. You document root has to be `what_you_have_now/Symfony2/web`. Please check that and then restart your web server, clear your Symfony2 cache with `app/console cache:clear` and then access this URL : `localhost/app_dev.php`

Comment: I cleared my cache as you said and I got this error:
_Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /Users/david/Sites/Symfony/app/autoload.php on line 35_

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks to that error I realised that when I re-installed Symfony I deleted _vendors_ folder, so that's why I was getting a blank page.
Funny how that silly mistake is not commented in any forum...

Comment: I don't think setting perms to 777 is a good answer - at least for long-term. Sure it let's EVERYONE rwx and thus, makes it simple to start with. However, once the webserver starts writing files you, as a user, will no longer be able to run app/console to manage anything because the web server user and group now owns the files inside and they will be 755 and 644

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but sudo chmod -R 777 * works for me and nothing else seems to work

Comment: Great answer, but take a note that it's Symfony executed as php script on behalf of web server is responsible for cache creation, not web server itself, because of that the owner of created files could be different from user configured on web server, depending of php module configuration(in case of dealing with Symfony in preconfigured environment)

Answer (score 9):

The [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) under the "Setting up permissions" says that if your system doesn't support chmod +a you have to do this:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

If that doesn't work try this:

```
umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775

// or

umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

First solution worked for me. I hope it helps someone with the same type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*


APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

**`Source:`** http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: His is on Mac OS X, this is for linux distributions with setfacl installed.

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted answer is great however, in my case (Centos 7 & Symfony 4.3) even after setting permissions i was still getting error. It turns out **SELinux** was blocking Apache.
The following worked for me(change my-project to your Symfony install folder).

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/my-project/var/cache/
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/my-project/var/log/
```

You can also disable SELinux but only temporarily for the current session to isolate the issue(I don't recommend this for prod)

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520370/permission-issue-in-cache-and-logs-folder-in-symfony-2-0)