# Permission issue in cache and logs folder in Symfony 2.0

Tags: symfony

I have tried some ways to give permission to the `cache` & `logs` folder but whenever I clear cache at that time the problem occurs like unable to write in directory.

I have tried this two ways:

1. Full access to cache via the `root` user with `777` permissions.
2. Change the owner like `www-data` as said in Symfony2 docs.

but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution:

Don't disable SELinux if you care about security if the site is global facing in anyway.  In this case you would want to "Use" SELinux, not disable it, it's there for a reason.

I do this;

```
# chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/symfonyapp/app/cache
# chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/symfonyapp/app/logs
# apachectl restart #(or systemctl restart httpd) or (service restart httpd) to restart your server, a reboot will suffice as well.
```

And yes, @Viataley has one good point, now you need to check to make sure your web server user `httpd`, `apache`, or `wwwdata` is added to your users group, whatever group your user is in.  This way when apache writes to the symfony directories that you user has recompiled through assetic when you run a cache clear for e.g., the `g` portion of the `ugo` which is your users group, will allow `apache` user permission to those dirs contents.

Comment: i find it odd that the system is such that i get 0 useful ticks on the question, but it was the accepted answer, and it does work.  Was setting it as `public_content_rw_t` somehow bettter or what?  I must be missing some kind of system manipulation techniques or something, dont want to know them...  my points are hard earned baby!

Comment: My sweet Jesus, I'd kiss you if see you in front of me. I tried everything from following symfony suggestions/cookbook to tons of answers here to no avail. This solved my issue!!!!!

Comment: Applying httpd_sys_script_rw_t also works for Symfony version 4 on Centos 7. I initially used public_content_rw_t but that did not allow write permissions to cache folder.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to turn off SElinux, here is a solution :

```
cd your/symfo/app
chcon -R -t public_content_rw_t app/cache
chcon -R -t public_content_rw_t app/logs
setsebool -P allow_httpd_anon_write 1
```

Comment: Changing the file context to public_content_rw_t has other implications, see output of `sesearch -t public_content_rw_t -AC`

Answer (score 3):

### Why it happens

The most common situation when such problem occurs - is when your web-server user does not have permission to write in the folder to which project belongs. Actually, changing the owner of app/cache and app/logs does not always help, because you may want to run some tests or console commands, which are executed from your user (php-cli/php-fpm). As result, cache or logs folder will be created from your current user and web-server user will not have access to it.

### Solution

My proposition is **either** to add web-server user (which is probably www-data) to your user group **or** run web-server from your user - and you'll forget about such problem forever ;)

Similar problem, well-explained answer:
[Permissions issues on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475794/permissions-issues-on-symfony2)

Comment: Normally this is the case, however in this case your dead wrong, its exactly the o pposite this time, its selinux, and selinux alone. i just ran through this issue.  the proper answer is by @Adrien LUCAS

Answer (score 2):

See the *Setting up Permissions* sidenote in the *[Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)* section. I recommend using the `setfacl` approach.

Answer (score -2):

**Temporary Solution:**

Permanently disable SElinux

To permanently disable SElinux you need to edit SElinux's config file /etc/selinux/config and add/alter line disable it:
SELINUX=disabled

**Note:** It's not safe to disable SElinux but for development environment it's ok.

**Permanent Solution:**

Good way to deal with permission issues is set permissions as per [official guideline](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/file_permissions.html).

Answer (score -3):

Turn off SELinux security using following command as su user.

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Comment: Do not disable SELinux. Learn to use it, it's a great tool to give you some degree of security.