# Symfony2 on FTP Webhoster

Tags: php, symfony, hosting

I wrote a little site with Symfony2 and I want to host it on my WebSpace. I only have FTP access, so I can not access any console/terminal!

Problem is: Symfony cannot create the cache directory properly! There might be a permission problem still?!

These are y steps so far:

1. Uploading my whole project with empty Cache directory (since I can't clean it due to no console)
2. Changing permissions of cache and logs directories using my ftp client
3. unmasking console, app.php and app_dev.php like explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)
4. Adding my IP to the whitelist in the files: config.php and app_dev.php
5. Checking the config.php to see if my configuration meets symfony's requirements (they do! no major problems!)
6. Checking PHP settings: PHP 5.3.3-7, SQLite3 and PDO-Driver there!
7. Opening `app_dev.php/_configurator/step/0` concludes into a RuntimeException:

   `RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/userx/html/MySiteSymfony/app/cache/dev/twig/83/4c).`
8. Opening app.php results in a 500 server error and no log file is being created

**Someone an idea how to get symfony working?**

Comment: I found the answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520370/permission-issue-in-cache-and-logs-folder-in-symfony-2-0) helped me to fix this issue.

Comment: How do I do that without console/terminal access?

Comment: 1. Could you ask your host for temporary ssh access? 2. Is there any host support you could ask to run the commands 3. Did you try option three in the linked doc, 'Without using ACL'? 4. Have you tried changing the permissions of the app directory as well?

Comment: 1.+2. My Hosts says: there is no ACL possibly with his OS. 3. I tried to unmask on a lot of files, also the directly linked ones. 4. I have given full permissions to all files and directories now. Seems odd to me.

Comment: Any Idea where I can find help for this? Really want to deploy this :)

Comment: It does seem odd. I have to admit, I've never fully understood why this issue of file ownership seems to cause so many problems. It seems making directories ugo writeable should solve everything. However this has not always been my experience and I find some hosts more problematic than others which makes no sense to me. You said you tried umask on a lot of files. Did you actually try putting umask(0000); at the beginning of the app/console, web/app.php and web/app_dev.php files as suggested in the Symfony docs?

Comment: Yes, and almost any other php file in app/ and web/ directories! But the pootstrap.php.cache file (don't know exactly where to unmask there). Maybe I will try another hoster next :-(

Comment: If using a different host is an option then I recommend using one that provides ssh access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally changed my provider. Seems like its OS was just deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the app/ folder click "get info" on the cache folder and set the right permissions (make sure to click "Apply to enclosed folders/files").

Comment: I did that already (2.). There is no app/cache/prod directory yet. I changed the app/cache permissions to '777' and checked the recursive change option in my ftp client.