# Permissions issue for Symfony on Centos vm

Tags: php, apache, symfony, permissions

Good evening.
I thought I wuold never have to ask this question... but I have no idea where to look anymore.

Here is the issue.

I installed Symfony on a brand new Centos 7 vm running in hyper v.

My apache user is apache.
My app/cache and app/logs directory are owned by apache user and apache group.
I have even set permissions of these 2 folders and subfolders to 777.

But still Symfony can't write in cache nor logs.

How is this possible? I would love to have some directions with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer to this question solved the problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520370/permission-issue-in-cache-and-logs-folder-in-symfony-2-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CentOS you must log as root a write this:

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t .../cache -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t .../logs -R
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable selinux : [https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html][1]. That solve my problem.

1- Open /etc/sysconfig/selinux and modify the value of SELINUX from permissive (or enforcing) to disabled

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

2- Restart your computer and test.

Comment: could you please paste a snippet of the configuration or command needed to answer the question, in case the external link is down or moved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is the best way to set up permissions:

http://symfony.es/documentacion/como-solucionar-el-problema-de-los-permisos-de-symfony2/

Always work for me.

The link is in spanish, but I'm sure you can understand it watching the commands (if not speak spanish).

Comment: Hi @mangelsnc and thank you for your answer. I had tried this as this is quite in line with what Symfony doc is also proposing. For some reasons it didn't work on my centos release. Maybe I had an issue with setfacl implementation on my VM... However I worked around it with a fresh install of ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the "Setting permissions" section in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: Yeap... I tried the three solutions already. None of them work.

Comment: Don't you have any log message from Symfony ?

Comment: Yes but nothing more than what I reported above.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really a solution but more a workaround.
I have replaced the centos vm by ubuntu and now everything runs smoothly just be ensuring the folders are owned by apache user.
It is really a mystery to me. And I realise that I had never deployed a symfony application on centos before. I am sure there should be an explaination but obviously not that easy to find.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Replacing an entire OS due to SELinux isn't a work-around.  It's avoiding system security all together.  You could have just disabled SELinux.  @Libor comment is the proper way to configure SELinux to allow Apache to write to the file system.