# Permissions Symfony2 on Mac: Either Apache _www or my user can access cache files

Tags: macos, apache, symfony

I'm using the default Apache on Mac, Symfony 2.
Following [Permissions issues on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475794/permissions-issues-on-symfony2), I tried `rm -rf app/cache/*` and `chmod 777 app/cache` afterwards.

That works. But...

**a)**
When Symfony 2 writes any cache files first, my user does not have access to the files afterwards. So clearing the cache via `app/console cache:clear` results in... `[RuntimeException]

  Unable to write in the "/Workspace/MyProject/app/cache/dev" directory`
I tried to compensate by running `sudo app/console cache:clear`. But then ...

**b)**
As soon as I clear the cache using `app/console cache:clear` or `sudo app/console cache:clear` and then reload the page, Apache can't access the files:
`RuntimeException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 239: Failed to write cache file "/Workspace/yProject/app/cache/dev/classes.php".`

I tried to delete the files and set the ACLs granting read and write for both, me and _www via the Mac GUI. But the result was the same as above.

It looks like only the owner (tested using `chown`) can access the files when apache runs as sudo. And Apache has to run as sudo when using port 80, else `apachectl start` would throw `This operation requires root.`. I found out there's tricky ways who to use port 8080 and redirect 80. But I want to understand the basic problem.

*Why is it that either apache or me who has access but not both?*

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: Workaround: Of course I can delete the folders within the cache directory via `sudo rm -rf app/cache/*`, but I'd really love to use `app/console cache:clear` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what the problem was but I found a sloution. I zpped the folder and unzipped the files. I hoped they would lose all permissions and so they did. The unzipped files work out fine now. If somebody knows a reason, I would still be interested.